SAP ARIBA REST API - Rate Limit
Hi I am new and hope to finde some information here.
For a customer we are retrieving data from SAP ARIBA via the REST API.
To build daily reports we want e.g. retrieve information from the  /vendors/{vendorId}/workspace/questonaires endpoint.
We have 2 options:

Delta loading - retrieving with filter the last Modified entries

Full Loads - regularly loading the data fully


Both approaches hit some problems.
Delta Loading
Loading only last Modified will not give us information of entries that are deleted (at least we believe so).
So, we would never notice it.
Full Load
The Rest API has rate limits, limiting on how many requests we can make per second/minute/hour/day.
With 60.000 - 70.000 vendorIds/requests we need to make, we exceed that by far.
If anyone has any solution to either one of these problems, I would be very thankful
